# Get data from SQL Server using linq

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq

I'm using this Linq code to get all variables from database, but first I just want to get first 6 rows of data:

```
 infos = infos.Where(q => q.ParentSId != null).ToArray();
 searchConds.CountrySIds = infos.Select(q => q.SId).ToArray();
```

So how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using "Take":

```
infos = infos.Where(q => q.ParentSId != null).Take(6).ToArray();

searchConds.CountrySIds = infos.Select(q => q.SId).Take(6).ToArray();
```

I dont know if you want to limit on first or second instruction.

Happy to Help you

Comment: Igor Quirino first thansk for ur reply, im using this method get first get 6 data after then search another data not showing on my table, use this method everytime just showing firts 6 data

Comment: Use take only on second call

Comment: first instruction is right not use to  change, but second instruction, when i open a page first time just getting 6 data after searching i ll be get all data.

Comment: I dont understand... What you want to do?

Comment: ok, i got a problem. 

 foreach (var info in infos)
                {
                  
                        htmlTh = new TableHeaderCell();
                        htmlTh.Text = info.Name;
                        htmlTr.Cells.Add(htmlTh);
                        
                }
when i get a data on  foreach (var info in infos) this statement still taking all data but i wantto take just 6 data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.Take(6)` like this:

`infos = infos.Where(q => q.ParentSId != null).Take(6).ToArray();`